# Размер шрифта в paint.setTextSize не соответствует высоте буквы

Tags: java, android, шрифты, android-drawable

Заметил что размер шрифта в Paint (возможно и в TextView, но не проверял) какой-то "левый".
Как я понимаю размер шрифта должен соответствовать высоте заглавной буквы. А он не соответствует! Высота буквы приблизительно в полтора раза меньше размера шрифта.
Попробовал нарисовать прямоугольник, высота которого равна размеру шрифта, а ширина размеру текста:

```
        rect.set(symbCoord[0],symbCoord[1],symbCoord[0]+(int)pSymbol.measureText(symbol),symbCoord[1]-symbSize);
```

и вот что получилось[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это так и должно быть? Есть ли какой-нибудь документ где разработчики андроид сообщают, что они понимают под размером шрифта?

Comment: Нашел, что я оказывается здорово ошибался:"Сам размер шрифта определяется как высота от базовой линии до верхней границы кегельной площадки." Т.е. высота заглавной буквы ничего не значит, главное бессмысленная для дилетанта "высота кегельной площадки".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это так и должно быть и это так везде. Пространство резервируется под всякие штуковины выше и ниже.

```css
p {
  line-height: 64px;
  font-size: 64px;
  background: silver;
  margin: 32px 0;
}

p + p {
  line-height: normal;
}
```

```html
<p>AЁр¶║█</p>
<p>AЁр¶║█</p>
```